# SharePoint 2010 Error in SSRS Report - The permission granted to 'domain\currentuser' are insufficient for performing this operation

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

I am getting following error when opening SSRS report in SharePoint 2010:

> SQL Server Reporting Services     Report Server Catalog
>     0000    Unexpected  Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException:
>   ,
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException:
>   The permissions granted to user 'domain\currentuser' are insufficient
>   for performing this operation

Detailed error in ULS logs:

> 0x38E0    SQL Server Reporting Services   Report Server Catalog
>     0000    Verbose     UnauthorizedAccessException in
>   GetSPItemMetaDataAndContent : System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetMetadataForUrl(String
>   bstrUrl, Int32 METADATAFLAGS, Guid& pgListId, Int32& plItemId, Int32&
>   plType, Object& pvarFileOrFolder)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetObjectForUrl(String strUrl, Guid&
>   listId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetObject(String strUrl)
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Objects.RSSPImpWeb.GetObject(String
>   strUrl)     at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Server.Utility.GetSPItemMetaDataAndContent(ItemSpecifier
>   itemSpecifier, UserContext userContext, Boolean returnContent, Boolean
>   wrapFileNotFoundOnOpenWeb, Byte[]& content)

Even I get the same error when editing the data connection used by the report.

Any ideas what could be the root cause of this issue and the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says that you dont have the required permission to run the job.

Try this:

under Site setting in Reports manager >Configure system-level role definitions > check ExecuteReport Defination option then Create a System UserGroup, Give the access to that group at Connect to your reporting Services Data base in server properties and add a group and permite the access as System User... It should work

and go through this link as well:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb630430.aspx

Regards
Safi

Comment: Yes but i am not sure where the permissions are missing to be assigned, because the error also occurs for administrator user